# The server was unable to save the form at this time

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I have several users on a single site collection that have edit access to a library. They can add and edit documents with no issue. However, when it comes to modifying the name of an existing file title or folder, they get a form error that states:

> The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.

Comment: check this http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/10/the-server-was-unable-to-save-form-at-this-time-please-try-again.html

Comment: You check if you have available space on the database?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that this is because off low memory. pay attention that the minimum requirement for SharePoint is 16G and if SQL server runs on the same server, you will need more than 16G ram. Add your memory and check again.

Restart the SharePoint Search Host Controller in services.msc, and perform iisreset. And then try to edit/save the item.

Please check the link,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084382/sharepoint-the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again